# I need a way of using the input from my UI in my code

Tags: c#, user-interface

I use c# for coding and I made a Window for some input. My problem is I don´t know how to use the input in my code for some calculation.

I also used Tags to send a certain information by clicking something but I don´t know how to use it further.

Thanks for the Help :)

This for example is a combobox I put into my UI and i want it to give the chosen word as a string into my code in another class for some calculations

```
        private void cbi_Gewindetyp_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)sender;
            String SechskantGewindetyp = Convert.ToString(cbi.Content);
        }
```

or I have this one as well with tags

```
private void cbi_Gewinde_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)sender;
            double SechskantGewinde = Convert.ToDouble(cbi.Tag);          
        }
```

I´m not sure if its enough for you to help me if you still need more please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

first of all dont compare `string` for calculate or something like that . For standardization i prefer use `enums`.

1- Create new `enums` for your project .

```
public enum Module: int
    {
        Stock = 0,
        Current = 1,
        Report = 2,

    }
```

2- bind to `combobox` (on load etc.)

```
cbModule.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Module));
```

3- Then get selected `enum` after that  do whatever you want

```
Module SelectedModule;
Enum.TryParse<Module>(cbModule.SelectedValue.ToString(),out SelectedModule);
```

[image: Example]